# Facebook Webhook Leads - callback url 404

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Im trying to setup and webhook for facebook leads, i've followed the tutorial that is given. Everything works fine and all the verification steps through the Graph explorer are "OK". My endpoints seams to live and working.

But when i try the Lead Ads Testing Tool and make an request to send the form i get the status "404 rejected"

I have verified that the callback url is correct, both via the Graph explorer and the webinterface on developer.facebook.com under the tab "Webhooks"

[image]

I have logs on the server so i can see all types of requests done to the url, empty or not and i don't even get an request. I've tried to rule out every possible "auth" problems.

So i'm stuck guys, what is missing? What i'am doing wrong?

Comment: Are there AAAA/IPv6 records for your domain specified in the DNS settings? If so, check if those are correct - Facebook prefers IPv6 over v4, and that can cause problems sometimes, when the IPv6 setup is not correct. (This would not explain why you were able to do the verification part, but I don’t have any other idea right now. If it was your server answering with a 404, then at least you should be able to find the request in the log files …)

Comment: Thank you @CBroe i done som tests and it seams to do something with that.